# How to view counterCache in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

Following the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/view/816/counterCache-Cache-your-count

I have this code in my model:

```
class Ticket extends AppModel {
   var $belongsTo = array(
      'TicketStatus' => array('counterCache' => true)
);
```

and this from my view/index.ctp:

```
echo $ticket_count
```

but it errors out instead of printing the content of that field. I've already added ticket_count (INT) to my tickets table. What have I missed?

Thanks

Lyman

Comment: "It *doesn't* errors out"? That's... good then? Please be more descriptive of what you get and what you expect. If you get errors, the full error message would be helpful. More code would be helpful too.

Comment: Hi, sorry bout the typo I have updated the post. Here's what the error is: Undefined variable: ticket_count [APP\views\ticket_statuses\index.ctp, line 40]...What I want really is to display the counter to my index.ctp. echo $ticket_count does not do that.

Comment: Where are you setting `$ticket_count`? *Are* you setting `$ticket_count`?

Comment: I have this code on my controller:
$pending = $this->ticketStatus->find('all',array('ticketStatus.ticket_count' => 'suspended'));
My problem is how to call $pending from my index view. I tried $this->ticketStatus->pending but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the $pending variable to be used in the view?

```
$this->set(compact('pending'));
```

Then is yout view:

```
echo $pending['TicketStatus']['ticket_count'];
```